# ListView using SimpleCursorAdapter not clickable

Tags: customization, simplecursoradapter, clickable

I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter with a custom layout file. When I try to populate this layout in the ListView, the items are not clickable. I put android attribute of the fields in the layout file for clickable to try fix that, but it's not working.

I think that attribute clickable is "true" for default. When I use the default layout file from "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" the items on list goes clickable. I think that a simple change in the layout file shouldn't interfere with the clickable attribute, but it's what I'm seeing.

This code doesn't work:

```
mSelection = mNotesAdapter.fetchAllNotes();    
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.note_row, mSelection, new String[] { "title"}, 
new int[] { R.mostrador.title});    
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This code works:

```
mSelection = mNotesAdapter.fetchAllNotes();    
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mSelection, new String[] { "title"}, 
new int[] { R.mostrador.title});    
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your first code will not work because `R.mostrador.title` is not the id of the TextView in the layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. Try to replace it with `android.R.id.text1`.

2) If you want to select an item in your ListView, you should change the background of the selected item:

```
<ListView
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:listSelector="#cccccc" 
    .../>
```

Comment: Thanks Hiep. I had forgotten to change the android.R.id.text1 when I have posted. I have tried to do what you have suggested, but my problem persists, :( .

Comment: I erased my project and I wrote a new one, and the code worked! XD

Comment: Helios don't forget to accept the answer if it is good.  Noticed you said "Thank you" on another one too, but that is the way to 'thank' someone here.